# Lua open socket error

Tags: sockets, http, nginx, lua, openresty

I am using lua as module for nginx (openresty) to get files from remote host. My function:

```
function readfile(url)
  local http = require ("socket.http")
  if not http then
    error("Couldn't open socket.http")
  end
  http.TIMEOUT = 5
  local body, code = http.request(url)
  if not body then
    error("Couldn't read the remote file: " .. code)
  end
  return body
end
```

I have tested this code by using Siege. When I set the users more then 100 (for example), I catch this error:

> 2018/03/27 09:36:38 [info] 10#10: *91018 shutdown() failed (107: Socket not connected), client: 172.18.0.7, server: localhost

I have more errors when i set more users. What does it mean? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use luasocket library with OpenResty. The resulting code would block on `http.request()`.

I suppose that all nginx worker just blocked and it is the reason of these errors.

For you purpose you may use one of the libraries below:

- [lua-resty-http](https://github.com/pintsized/lua-resty-http)
- [lua-resty-http-simple](https://github.com/bakins/lua-resty-http-simple)

First is more fexible, allow to use secure transport.
Second has simpler API.

And both use internally nginx Lua cosocket API and are 100% nonblocking out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

The lua-resty-http or lua-resty-http-simple do not work in the init_by_lua in http context.
it is fine to use it in the init context where blocking is not considered harmful.